# How to send a result of query in email using nodemailer in node.js

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodemailer

I am making password recovery system in which i am getting password from database when email matches by the email entered by user. I want to send password in the mail but i am getting an error of [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE].

I am getting result from database but mail is not sending because of that arg error.

How i can send that password in mail and how to correct that error?

```
app.post('/mail', (request, response) => {
  var e = request.body.e;
  console.log(e);
    var password = request.body.pwd;

    
    var sql = ` SELECT Employer_Password 
        FROM fyp_employers 
        WHERE Email_Address = ?`;
   var pass= connection.query(sql, [e], function (error, results, fields) {
      if(error){
        console.log(error);
      }
      else{

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'xyz@gmail.com',
    pass: 'un3560'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'palwashanaz1@gmail.com',
  to: request.body.e ,
  subject: 'Okay' ,
  text: results,
};
}

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
});

})
app.listen(3000);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your body should be a string or you can send html file, because mails are just text, One thing you can do is to loop through the array and make a string from the elements of the array.

let text='';

```
array.forEach(ele=>{
  text=text+String(ele)+' ';
})
```

Comment: I can store the password in some variable and then send it to mail?

Comment: But in you said you wanted to send array, keep in mind try to convert everything into string before sending